# How can I notify that I successfully created a sql pool in express js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm creating a restful API using mysql and expressjs, here's an example of how I send requests to my database:

**server.js:**

```js
const express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    PORT = 8080,
    app = express();

//setting up routes
const userRoute = require('./routes/user.route');

//parsebody of req into json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use('/user', userRoute);

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`API fired up on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
)
```

**userRoute**:

```js
const express = require('express');
const userRoute = express.Router();
const User = require('../controllers/user.controllers');

// Retrieve all Users
userRoute.route('/users').get(((req, res) => {
  User.findAll(req,res);
}));
```

**userController:**

```js
const User = require("../models/user.model.js");

// Retrieve all Customers from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    User.getAll((err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving user."
            });
        else res.send(data);
    });
}
```

**userModel:**

```js
const sql = require('../tools/db');

User.getAll = result => {
    sql.query("SELECT * FROM Utilisateur", (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("erreur: ", err);
            result(null, err);
            return;
        }

        console.log("Utilisateurs: ", res);
        result(null, res);
    });
};
```

**db:**

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const dbConfig = require("../config/database.config");

// Create a connection to the database
const connection = mysql.createPool({
        host: dbConfig.HOST,
        user: dbConfig.USER,
        password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
        database: dbConfig.DB,
        port: dbConfig.PORT
    }) || null;

/*if(connection) console.log("Connected to "+ connection.config.database +" database!")*/

module.exports = connection;
```

My request works perfectly but I'm trying to console log the fact that my API successfuly connected to my database, (I commented my attempt) but the log gives me a:

```
Connected to undefined database!
```

is there a best way to log my connection success (and maybe handle if there's any error in the process) ? if not how can I make `connection.config.database` correctly write my database name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're calling an `undefined` property in the connection object.

This should work just fine:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createPool({
        host: dbConfig.HOST,
        user: dbConfig.USER,
        password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
        database: dbConfig.DB,
        port: dbConfig.PORT
});

const database = connection.config.connectionConfig.database;
console.log(`Connected to ${database} database!`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the `mysql.createPool` function has finished executing before calling `console.log`.

Try this change:

```js
const connection = mysql.createPool({
        host: dbConfig.HOST,
        user: dbConfig.USER,
        password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
        database: dbConfig.DB,
        port: dbConfig.PORT
    }).then(con => {
        console.log(con.config.databse)
        return con
    })
```

Comment: it seems that `TypeError: mysql.createPool(...).then is not a function
`